# JSR082 - LocalDevice.getLocalDevice() returns null

Tags: java, bluetooth, jsr82

Using JSR082_1.1.jar from Java Wireless Toolkit 3.0,
I'm trying to get the local device (for later discovery of others)
but i keep getting null for the call 
LocalDevice.getLocalDevice()

while in the docs they say this method cannot return null...
[docs](http://bluecove.org/bluecove/apidocs/javax/bluetooth/LocalDevice.html#getLocalDevice%28%29)

My bluetooth is ON, checked on 2 computers (Win7 & OSX 10.6)

Help!
Thanks

Comment: What Bluetooth driver stack are you using at least for Windows, and second is it a x86 or x64 architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the JSR-82 JAR file distributed with the Wireless Toolkit contains only the interfaces, not a working implementation of the Bluetooth API. This allows you to compile code that uses JSR-82 but not to test it.

You should get a copy of [Bluecove](http://www.bluecove.org), a free implementation of JSR-82 you can run on the desktop. Make sure you're using the 32-bit JVM, though (use the `-d32` command line argument).

Comment: Thank you! both Bluecove and the link and the -d32 comments were spot on!